# jquery ui containment with scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to implement drag and drop feature using jquery ui. I have a container with position 'relative' and inside it, there are draggable elements having position 'absolute'. What I want is, to restrict the draggable elements within the container and also the ability to scroll the elements beyond the container. So I initialized the draggables like:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
 containment:'parent',
 scroll:true
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zjncn6zy/1/

But it is not working as expected. when i remove the 'containment' option, the draggables are auto scrollable but within the body, not within the container.

What i need is, as i drag the draggables beyond the container, the draggables need to auto scroll within the container.

Please help me to solve my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the container to `overflow: auto;`